# What steps should I take to install gym[box2D] in Python without encountering 'Failed building wheel for box2d-py' error?

Tags: python, openai-gym

I attempted to install gym[box2D], but I always get the error, can somebody help me out

```
The following is the detail error message:
"Building wheels for collected packages: box2d-py, moviepy, gym, atomicwrites
  Building wheel for box2d-py (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error


  × Building wheel for box2d-py (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      Using setuptools (version 67.8.0).
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\Box2D
      copying library\Box2D\Box2D.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\Box2D
      copying library\Box2D\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\Box2D
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\Box2D\b2
      copying library\Box2D\b2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\Box2D\b2
      running build_ext
      building 'Box2D._Box2D' extension
      swigging Box2D\Box2D.i to Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp
      swig.exe -python -c++ -IBox2D -small -O -includeall -ignoremissing -w201 -globals b2Globals -outdir library\Box2D -keyword -w511 -D_SWIG_KWARGS -o Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp Box2D\Box2D.i
      error: command 'swig.exe' failed: None
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for box2d-py"
```